# Custom array sorting based on instance properties

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to perform a `usort` on an array inside an instance of a class.  But the sort is dependent on the properties of said instance.

Code (which doesn't work):

```
class foo {
  private $array;
  private $key;
  private $dir;

  function sort() {
    usort($this->array, array("foo", "orderArray"));
  }

  function orderArray($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a[$this->key], $b[$this->key]) * $this->dir;
  }
}
```

From the `orderArray` class, you **can't access $key or $dir**.  The question is, **how can I write this so I can?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you just want to see the current instance? Pass it in the callback.

```
  function sort() {
    usort($this->array, array($this, "orderArray"));
  }
```